# htaccess conditional rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am fiddling around with .htaccess and mod_rewrite. I have a site that has two types of URLs which I want to rewrite:

- `/index.php?nav=$2`
- `/index.php?nav=41&intNewsId=$3` -- 41 is static, the news nav is always 41

I want to rewrite them to:

- `/pagename/id`
- `/news/pagename/id`

I already made a piece of code that works, BUT if I add the last line the second line stops working, and **I can imagine thats because the conditions in the third block are also true for the second block**. But I cant figure out how to use conditions right. (Both blocks work individual)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# Reroute rules that end on / 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])$ /$1/$2/ [R] 

# Make the system understand pagename/96
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])/$ /index.php?nav=$2 

# Make the system understand news/pagename/99
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)\/([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])/$ /index.php?nav=41&intNewsId=$3
```

I tried everything I could think of, but I'm not too familiar with this regex style of typing or conditional blocks in htaccess.

Solution:
I fixed my own code, I just stripped the second $ so the condition didnt interfere with the last one

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# Reroute rules that end on / 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])$ /$1/$2/ [R] 

# Make the system understand pagename/96
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])/ /index.php?nav=$2 

# Make the system understand news/pagename/99
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)\/([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])/$ /index.php?nav=41&intNewsId=$3
```

Thanks for the answers all!

Comment: Why was this voted off-topic?

Comment: Also, note that you can avoid the clunkiness of those `[0-9]` constructs by just using `(\d+)`, which captures any block of one or more digits.

Comment: Aww thanks for that also Will. Notice my ([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]) , it was even worse before :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^news/.+/([^/]*)$ /index.php?nav=41&intNewsId=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^.+/([^/]*)$ /index.php?nav=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks man. Using this I got it working too :D What a day to learn ^^

Comment: @Hans Wassink: You are welcome! If my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking on the tick below the vote counts on the left of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, perhaps slightly more concise:

```
RewriteRule ^pagename/(\d+)$ index.php?nav=$1
RewriteRule ^news/pagename/(\d+)$ index.php?nav=41&intNewsId=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Make the system understand pagename/96
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pagename/([0-9]*)
RewriteRule .* /index.php?nav=%1

# Make the system understand news/pagename/99
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/news/pagename/([0-9]*)
RewriteRule .* /index.php?nav=41&intNewsId=%1
```

Comment: Thanks man, using this it worked (I changed pagename into a multichar regex check)

I fixed my own code work too btw, I just stripped the second $ so the condition didnt interfere with the last one

Comment: For the record, the `RewriteCond` statements can be elided with appropriate `RewriteRule`s :)

Comment: @Hans Wassink glad it worked. It is always good to write the rule by condition makes it more efficient.